# Viewing a single post with mongodb in react.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am starting a small blog. I would like to click on the post title and view the single post.
App.js page:

```
**import React from 'react'
import Nav from './Nav'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
const App = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState ([])
  useEffect (() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch (`http: // localhost: 3030 / api / posts`)
      const data = await res.json ()
      setPosts (date)
    }
    fetchData ()
  }, [])
  return (
      <div className = 'container p-5'>
        <Nav />
        <h1 style = {{marginTop: '20px'}}> MERN CRUD </h1>
        {
          posts.map ((post, id) => {
            return (
              <div key = {id} className = 'row' style = {{borderBottom: '3px solid black', paddingTop: '30px', paddingBottom: '30px'}}>
                <Link to = {`/ post / $ {post.slug}`}>
                <h1> {post.title} </h1>
                </Link>
                <h5> Created at: {new Date (post.createdAt) .toLocaleDateString ()} </h5>
                <h6> Written by: {post.user} </h6>
                <p> {post.content.substring (0, 100)} ...... </p>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
  )
}
export default App**
```

I would like to make the request via slug.
SinglePost.js page

```
**import React from 'react'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Nav from './Nav'
const SinglePost = (props) => {
     const [post, setPost] = useState ('')
     useEffect (() => {
         const fetchPost = async () => {
             const res = await fetch (`http: // localhost: 3030 / api / post / $ {props.slug}`)
             const data = await res.json ()
             setPost (date)
             console.log (date)
         }
         fetchPost ()
     }, [])
   return (
     <div>
        
         <Nav />
         <div> </div>
         <h1> {post.slug} </h1>
     </div>
   )
}
export default SinglePost**
```

This is the page with the query:

```
**exports.read = (req, res) => {
    const { slug } = req.params 
    Post.findOne({slug})
        .exec((err, post) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }else {
                res.json(post)
            }
            
    })
}**
```

I'm only shown the first post and I can't figure out how to view the specific post.
Thank you for your help

Comment: I did not understand if it is a question or a criticism or sarcasm or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a `Routes` component responsible for handling the redirect to a single post in your `index.js` file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
      <Route path='/post' element={<SinglePost />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

Also, you should use the `useParams` hook to retrieve the `slug` parameter in the `SinglePost` component:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SinglePost = () => {
     const { slug } = useParams();
     ...
```

Comment: THANKS LUCA. Grazie mille adesso ci sono riuscito. FANTASTICO